# How to assert code format with Cypress inside a code editor

Tags: reactjs, cypress, integration-testing, monaco-editor

I must check if a block code inside a code editor is formatted in the UI of the application.

The block code is received from a request and is already minified. When the Monaco editor instance is mounted in the view, there is a trigger that runs the action of formatting the document. And it does and works. When the user clicks save, the code gets minified again and posts to an endpoint.

It is an application in React. As I said, the Monaco editor uses the wrapper for React ([react-monaco-editor](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor). For integration tests, Cypress is used.